# How to troubleshoot "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." when creating a site with IIS Express appcmd?

Tags: iis-express

Please, observe:

```
PS D:\> &"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" add site /name:MySite /physicalPath:C:\MySite /bindings:http/*:51000:localhost /commit
SITE object "MySite" added
APP object "MySite/" added
VDIR object "MySite/" added
ERROR ( hresult:800700b7, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.  

Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

 )
```

The most frustrating thing is that it used to work a week or so ago, but now it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the reason. The **%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config** contained a `<location>` item for the site I was trying to add. That caused the error.